# Pose Mixing Blender 2.8

Tags: rigging

I just came over from Blender 2.79. I do a lot of work with characters I have created. A while ago I found an addon that allowed me to mix poses from my pose library to create something in between two poses.

This is the addon I used in the past. It is not available for Blender 2.8.

https://github.com/TheDuckCow/pose-tools

Edit: I make a lot of animations for character models. Having the ability to create the first and last pose in animation and than mix those poses to create the in-between saves me a lot of time.

In 2.79 I used an addon that allowed me to choose the percentage of two separate poses and make a pose that was in-between the two poses I had made.

Hoping there is something like this in 2.8, either a function I have missed or an addon I am unaware of.

If anyone has any suggestions or addons that handle pose mixing let me know.

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: You can copy-paste keyframes between actions so you can fade from one pose to other without any addon.

Comment: Duarte: My question was how can I do the same thing in Blender 2.8

FFeller: Not sure I understand how to do that. I don't make the animations in blender, I make the models and take pictures of them and make 'sprite sheets' out of them.